# iPhone calculate numbers between 0-50 for custom slider

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview

[image]

I want to calculate numbers between 0 to 50 when user move on the slider right and left. I am using a formula such as but didn't succedded.

**(point.x + 100) / 20**

Where point.x is a CGPoint getting with locatioOfView: method between two UIView's

```
CGPoint point = [sender locationInView:self.viewBaseSlider];
```

**Note :** Here self.viewBaseSlider is not a slider it is a Custom View.

Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: you can directly get self.viewBaseSlider.value

Comment: @anbu.Karthik viewBaseSlider is a custom uiview

Comment: @DarshanMothreja - then initally fetch the subviews then subview isequal to your slider then take the diret slider value

Comment: Why not make viewBaseSlider a subclass of `UIControl` and set its value as it moves, and send a `didChange` action? Then you can use it just like you would a `UISlider`

Comment: _wot...?_ why don't you use `UISlider`? you could customise it visually as well.

Comment: @holex I thought the customisation with UIView would be much easier

Comment: @DarshanMothreja, no offence but... not particularly, however it is up to you; if you have enough time to develop an own 'slider' instead of using the existing system-component, that is okay; but seemingly you are struggling to do that (according to your post), so that is why it would be better for you to use a built-in component (`UISlider`) which can do the job for you initially then you could customise it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to translate `location` from range between 0 to `your-custom-view-width` to range from 0 to `your-slider-max` (50 in this case).

Here's my take on it in `swift`:

```
let maxPoints = 50
let customViewWidth = customView.frame.size.width
let pointWidth = Float(customViewWidth) / Float(maxPoints)

if let touch = touches.first {
    let location = touch.location(in: customView)
    let point = Int(roundf(Float(location.x) / pointWidth))
    print("Selected \(point)")
}
```

And here's working example, where grey area is `customView` and output in console comes from clicking in the start, around the middle and the end of the grey region:

[image: demo]